# what is the definition of the doubly- transitive permutation group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can you give me the definition of the doubly transitive permutation groups? Or any reference?

I know what its mean by transitive permutation group.

Answer (score 2):

A permutation group is ***doubly transitive*** (or ***2-transitive***) if it acts transitively on distinct pairs of elements.

To be precise, let $G$ be a group of permutations of a set $X$.  Then $G$ is ***doubly transitive*** if for all $a,b,c,d\in X$ with $a\ne b$ and $c\ne d$, there exists a $g\in G$ so that $g(a)=c$ and $g(b)=d$.

[This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply_transitive_group#Multiply_transitive_groups) has some information on multiple transitivity.  Chapter 9 of Rotman's *An Introduction to the Theory of Groups* is a pretty good introductory reference, and Dixon's *Permutation Groups* has the complete theory.